# TSQL Recursive Query Over Looping Dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, recursion

Please find the below code :

```
WITH
CTE(col1, col2, col3, Hier) AS (
       SELECT
         t.col1,
         t.col2,
         t.col3,
         CAST('/' + LTRIM(t.col2) + '/' AS VARCHAR(MAX))
         FROM TABLE t
        WHERE t.col2 = 1

       UNION ALL

        SELECT
          t.col1,
          t.col2,
          t.col3,
          hier + CAST(t.col2 AS VARCHAR(MAX)) +'/'
          FROM TABLE T 
         INNER JOIN CTE ON T.col3 = CTE.col3
         WHERE CTE.Hier NOT LIKE '%/' + CAST(T.col2 AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '/%'
)
```

I have an issue with the above query which goes into an infinite loop. Basically my dataset contains many data loops and the usual hierarchy check does not work as detailed below in **"Why It Doesn't Work"**.

I thought about using a table variable to store entries then checking on it in the recursive query section but cannot find a way to insert into said table variable from inside the recursive query.

I also have considered functions and re-writing in C# but thought there must surely be a away of doing it here in TSQL.

Any ideas / solutions would be fantastic.

**Why it doesn't work?**

There is a good 20 plus recursions in my query, below is a brief example extract

```
 T.col1 | T.col2 | T.col3 |               Hier
-------------------------------------------------------------
   1    |   2    |   3    |   /2/
   1    |   2    |   5    |   /2/
   1    |   3    |   3    |   /2/3/

 >>>>> Later In Query Results

  56    |  57    |   3    |   /2/3/5/6/32/34/36/47/48/50/57
  56    |  57    |   3    |   /2/3/5/6/32/34/36/47/48/50/52/57
```

The bottom row is identical to the one above apart from the Hier column and it appears because entry 1 has a `T.col3` value of `3` so it is joined and `T.col2` of the latest record has a value of `57` which does not appear in the Hier of entry `1` thus it is added and as this will always be the case rows are continuously added an the query continues to run.

I haven't included a dataset as it takes roughly 500+ records before the loop actually starts, hopefully I have provided enough information to give some idea of my issue.

Comment: Hi, this is a little confusing as to what you expect to see in your heir column based on the limited amount of data shown, could you expand and add a little bit of sample data with what you expect to see a little clearer?

Comment: As @JamiePollard says, a minimal example of what a 'data loop' looks like would help. An intermediate approach between a pure CTE and a C#-rewrite would be an iterative approach *in T-SQL*, using a `WHILE` loop and a temporary table.

Comment: This is happening because the in first part of the cte where you select the parent nodes you don't start from the root node in the table it should be something like `WHERE T.col2 is null`.